# Android Daydream Service fire/open activity

Tags: android

My use case is as follows:

I need one of my activities to be shown in the daydream selection menu **and should start as a daydream** .

Currently in the code i have implemented the daydream starts i get a black screen but when i press back i see my activity behind.

```
<service
            android:name=".ui.daydream.DayDream"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_DREAM_SERVICE">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.service.dreams.DreamService" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

In my daydream service I have implemented the following code:

```
public class DayDream extends DreamService {
    @Override
    public void onAttachedToWindow() {
        super.onAttachedToWindow();

        // Allow user touch
        setInteractive(true);

        // Hide system UI
        setFullscreen(true);

    }

    @Override
    public void onDreamingStarted() {
        super.onDreamingStarted();
        onDreamingStopped();
       // setContentView(R.layout.unassisted_fragment_dslr);

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityUnassisted.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT);

        startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDreamingStopped() {

    }
}
```

My pain point is how do i directly start my activity as a daydream screensaver.

Comment: Any solution you got?